# The latest method to implement login through facebook sdk in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am using 3.6 to implement the facebook login. From the official document it is quite abstract and not easy to follow . So I have found some tutorial on the internet . However, when I use the code in that tutorial it said the method is deprecated. Although it works, I afraid the offical will stop the function later. So, are there any way to implement the login/ post to wall / get personal info of the latest sdk ? Thanks

The login code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    // set permission list, Don't foeget to add email
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email"));
    // session state call back event
    authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Access Token" + session.getAccessToken());
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "User ID " + user.getId());
                                    Log.i(TAG,
                                            "Email "
                                                    + user.asMap().get(
                                                            "email"));
                                    lblEmail.setText(user.asMap()
                                            .get("email").toString());
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
```

In the code Request.executeMeRequestAsync is deprecate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this  [FACEBOOK LOGIN NEW SDK](http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2013/12/android-facebook-login-using-facebook.html)

```
   Button button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_share);
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {    
if (fb_session != null && fb_session.isOpened()) {
  makeMeRequest(fb_session);     
  Log.i("Facebook Login State == >", "Facebook Login State");     
 } else {
  if (fb_session == null) {
   fb_session = new Session(mCurrContext);            
       }
  Session.setActiveSession(fb_session);
  ConnectToFacebook();
   Log.i("Facebook not Login State == >", "Facebook Not login State");
 }         
 }
});  
 }
```